# Ruby on Rails- Destroy record using link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to delete a record that is stored in a table using a link right next to the table data. The error I come up with is:

> No route matches [GET] "/carlogs/destroy"

My destroy method:

```
def destroy
@carlog= CarLog.find(params[:id])
@carlog.destroy()

redirect_to show_path(@carlog)
end
```

Part of the view code containing the Delete link:

```
<% @carlogs.each do |car| %>
<tr>
<td><%= car.id %></td>
<td><%= car.plate_number %></td>
<td><%= car.brand %></td>
<td><%= car.slot_number %></td>
<td><%= car.is_taken %></td>
<td><%= car.created_at %></td>
<td><%= link_to "Delete", show_path(car), method: :delete, data: 
        {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: run `rake routes` to see the correct path for deleting object.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have `delete` REST method as:

```
DELETE /carlogs/:id(.:format)                     carlogs#destroy
```

And in your `application.js` you must have this line:

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Answer (score 0):

Use destroy link for destroy record then redirect table like

method

```
def destroy
 @carlog= CarLog.find(params[:id])
 @carlog.destroy()

 redirect_to show_path(@carlog) #-> Table pathe
end
```

routes.rb

```
 delete 'destroy' => 'carlogs#destroy'
```

View

```
<%= link_to "Delete", destroy_path, method: :delete, data: 
    {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
```

I think will help you

Answer (score 0):

Why did you write show_path(car)?

Maybe you mean car_path(car) ?

`<%= link_to "Delete", car_path(car), method: :delete, data: 
        {confirm: "Are you sure?"}%>`

Also you should check your route `[GET] "/carlogs/destroy`.
I think this don't present in `rake router`